# Почему говорят "у меня не было Интернета"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Почему не говорят "у меня не был Интернет"? Ведь, "Интернет" — это мужской род, а "было" — средний.
Как это связать с родительным падежом?

Comment: "У меня не было дома", "у меня не было магнитофона", "у меня не было велосипеда". Почему для интернета должно быть исключение?

Answer (score 4):

Это безличные отрицательные предложения, в которых нет подлежащего. Сказуемое выражается частицей **нет или глаголом в безличной форме с отрицательной частицей не + дополнение в родительном падеже.**

**Ср.: Нет денег.
Не было денег.**

Comment: Чернила обычно берегут под конец, а здесь наоборот...

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Выделение «полужирным» выглядит неоправданным. Будто баллончик лопнул и ручка потекла.